# how to add multiple parameter in axios vue js

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

i want to add multiple parameter in my axios post. how i can do it?

here what i try

```
axios.post('/select-files', this.$data.single, formData, config)
                    .then((response) => {
                        alert('Data Single Successfull Inserted.')
                        console.log(response);
                    })
```

my current code only return data from `this.$data.single`.

if i change code like this `formData, this.$data.single, config`, then my code will only return data from `formData`

`formdata` is return this data

```
formData.append('image', this.image);
```

`this.$data.single` return this data

```
data() {
            return {
                files: [],
                errors: [],
                artistname: [],
                single: {},
                image: '',
                success: '',
                artist: [],
                showinput: [],
                searchText: '',
                items: [],
                lastSelectItem: {}
            }
        },
```

and `config` is

```
const config = {
                    headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
                }
```

this is not my full code.

Answer (score -4):

You could try this

```
   axios.post('/echo/json/', 'name='+this.name+'&pwd='+this.password, {headers: {
  'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}}).then(r => console.log('r: ', JSON.stringify(r, null, 2)));
```